# Url Rewrite Rule needs to disabled and enabled to IIS

Tags: iis, powershell, rewrite

I am automating the creation of a URL Rewrite in a testing environment. I am configuring it using Powershell in IIS 8.5

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location 'Default Web Site/App/MyApp/v1' -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/allowedServerVariables" -name "." -value @{name='HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'}
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location 'Default Web Site/App/MyApp/v1' -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/rules" -name "." -value @{name='Add X-Forwarded-For Header';patternSyntax='Wildcard'}
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location 'Default Web Site/App/MyApp/v1' -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/rules/rule[@name='Add X-Forwarded-For Header']/match" -name "url" -value "*"
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location 'Default Web Site/App/MyApp/v1' -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/rules/rule[@name='Add X-Forwarded-For Header']/serverVariables" -name "." -value @{name='HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR';value='{REMOTE_ADDR}';replace='False'}
```

This creates the rule however the IIS Application is broken when trying to make a request.

It throws an 500.52 error.

[image]

However, if the rule is disabled and enabled in the UI everything is fine. What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Your PowerShell code has in typo in the last line `HTTP_X_ORWARDED_FOR` has to be `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`

On IIS 10 this results in the error:

> HTTP Error 500.50 - The server variable "HTTP_X_ORWARDED_FOR" is not allowed to be set. Add the server variable name to the allowed server variable list.

With PowerShell you are updating the global `applicationhost.config`, when using the GUI, the changes are written into the web.config file. I have no idea why that fixes your problem. I still get the same error as before.

Fix the typo and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The typo was me moving the code to Server Fault. I've checked the original and it was cool.